# Build project using devenv.exe in TFS 15RC1 Build Server

Tags: powershell, tfs, build-server, devenv

I have a trouble with understanding how to use devenv.exe from TFS Build Server.

There is no default step to use devenv, so I tried to use PowerShell sсript to execute devenv.exe with parameters. There are no errors in build process but I see that build result files are not updated.
If I execute the script manually on a agent-machine, the build passes successfully. That is my script:

```
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", "/Rebuild ""MyConfig"" ""C:\agent\agent\_work\1\s\MyProject.sln"" /Project ""C:\agent\agent\_work\1\s\MyProject\MyProject.dwproj""") 
$process.WaitForExit()
```

As you see now I do not use variables for source paths, but I will use it if script will work.

I also have to say that I could not find any logs with errors. Maybe I do not know where to find them?

So,

1. What am I doing wrong in powershell script?
2. What is the best practice to build project using devenv.exe in TFS Build Server?

PS We are using TFS 15 RC1 (Version 15.103.25603.0).

Comment: Why do you use devenv instead of msbuild?

Comment: @just.ru I need to build SSAS project - .dwproj. MSBuild can't do it. =(

Comment: Which build are you using? The old XAML build or the new vNext build?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I want to use the vNext build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it doesn't work only when the agent is running as a service. When I started the agent in the interactive mode, my tasks started to work correctly. Why? - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no this build-in feature to support directly using `devenv.exe` in vNext build task. But seems will coming in the near future:

> That is not something we are working on right now, but it is something
>   that we would take a pull request for.
>
> *chrisrpatterson commented on Jan 8*
>
> We want an input on the existing Visual Studio Build task that says
>   use devenv (defaults to false). If true, it takes the variant path
>   running code similar to above.
>
> bryanmacfarlane commented on Jan 22
>
> Source from GitHUB:
>
> - ["Visual Studio Build" build step that actually invokes devenv.com    instead of msbuild?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/946)
> - [visual studio command-line build vnext step (devenv.com)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/pull/1080)

You can try to use a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/pull/1080/files) provide by *jmacnett* which creating a customize build task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Ok, directly devenv is not supported. But I tried to use Powershell task and Batch task for running devenv.exe. As far as I can see the devenv is started and is doing something, but the files in the bin folder are not updated...

Comment: Can you try to add a Copy task target the /bin folder when looking for the DLL files? Something as manually copy to workaround the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$argumentList = ("`"$solnPath`" /$solnCmdSwitch $solnConfigName")
```

if project then add folowing

```
$argumentList += (" /project `"$projPath`" /projectconfig $projConfigName")
```

See the extra back-quotes